# getting image name from an input field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

please help me out on this little problem. I want to get the name of the image (with NO path and file extension) from an input field before that the form is submitted!
in other words, I want to check if this two name are the same, then proceed, if not, then `return false;`

My JavaScript code:

```
var pic = document.getElementById("photo1").value;
if (gyuru == null || gyuru == "" || gyuru == " ")
{
    alert("Gyűrűszám nélkül nem lehet adatot lementeni!");
    x.focus();
    x.style.borderColor="#C30";
    return false;
}else if (gyuru != pic){
    alert("A kép neve nem egyezik meg a gyűrűszámal!");
    return false;
}
```

And the image input form data:

```
<input type="file" id="photo1" name="photo1"/>
```

Comment: I forgot to put on my code, that my "gyuru" is also declared this way: var gyuru = document.getElementById("gyuruszam").value; and the input for this is: <input type="text" id="gyuruszam" name="gyuruszam"/>

Comment: `x` is: `var x = document.getElementById("gyuruszam")` I'm using only to focus on him...if there is an error.

Comment: I just want to I can upload an image to server only if the name of the image is the same to `gyuru`, if it's no image selected, do nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the filename without extension:

```js
pic = pic.split('/').pop().split('\\').pop().replace(/[.][^.]+$/, "");
```

Comment: thank you very much! it's working, but can you help me out just a little, because even if I don't select image, it's entering in the second loop too...

Comment: @user3488958 Well, there is no check on the `pic` emptyness: `else if (gyuru != pic && pic != null && !pic.trim().length)`